# How large of an area of the earth's surface would we need to cover in mirrors to negate global warming?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, estimation, climate-science

How large of an area of the earth's surface would we need to cover in mirrors to negate current levels of global warming?

Let's assume that the reflective component of the mirror is made of aluminium foil and that it is kept clean.

And let's also forget about ocean acidification.  I'm only really interested in negating the retained heat component of atmospheric carbon.

Comment: It would depend where you put the mirrors, the albedo of the mirrors and on the albedo of the surface you covered, but the math shouldn't be too difficult for a ballpark answer.     A curious fact, mirrors aren't necessarily the most reflective surface.  Fresh snow reflects more light than most mirrors, it just doesn't reflect it as a clean image.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about engineering, which is the application of scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a specific problem. As such, it is off topic for this site, which deals with the science of how the natural world works. As you are seeking speculation on an outlandish hypothetical, you may wish to flag for moderator attention to request a migration to [worldbuilding.se], which handles that sort of thing.

Comment: Geoengineering is also on-topic on [EarthScience.SE], but building actual mirrors would be an extremely impractical way to do it.  We can increase the albedo by cutting down the Siberian forests, this will cool the Earth and is much easier.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Worldbuilding mod here. [Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is not a What-If site](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3033/627), despite what people continue to think. In the future, please do not suggest migrating random hypotheticals which are not actually about worldbuilding.

Comment: @CountTo10 See my comment above ^.

Comment: @HDE226868.  Sincerest apologies, lesson learnt.

Comment: @userLTK  the law of unexpected consequences would apply in cutting trees. Trees absorb carbon dioxide and store it as wood.